# Sending all routes or paths to angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

In my node js app.js I want that whatever the url is it goes to my angular/html page i.e. begin.html, app.js resides in server folder and begin.html is in client folder of my project. It's like :-

```
-Project
----Server
---------app.js
----Client
---------begin.html
```

What should I type in app.js so that all the urls go to begin.html where i am using Angular routing?? I think its something like..

```
var begin=require('../Client/begin.html);
app.use('*',begin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to just have all routes go back to that HTML page, then you could just use a web server like [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) serve that directory statically.

It looks like you are using Express, but that is just a guess. If you want to make HTTP requests from your Angular side to your Node.js side then you will probably want the default response to return your HTML, but still be able to allow requests through. I would look at using the `static` method from express to expose a static directory while still allowing you to build other routes (i.e. api routes).

It might look something like this:

```
// Already created express app above

/*
  This will default to using index.html from
  your Client directory and serve any other resources
  in that directory.
*/
app.use(express.static('../Client'));

// Any other routes

app.listen(3000); // Or whatever your port is
```

Or you could also implement it using the 404 error handler style and return your default file:

```
/*
  This comes after all of your other
  route and middleware declarations and
  before the .listen() call
*/
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../begin.html'));
});
```

Comment: If that worked for you please accept this as the answer so it can help others out as well. Thanks!